# VBA: Load only a UserForm from a different Document

Tags: vba, userform

Working in VBA here (complete beginner). I'd like a UserForm (e.g. "Master") in Doc1 to load a UserForm (e.g. "Apprentice) from Doc2 on a button click. **I don't want Doc2 to open - only its UserForm.**

After loading the "Apprentice" UserForm from Doc1, I want **its buttons' actions to apply to Doc1**. So for example, if the Apprentice UserForm has a button that adds a string of "Hello" to the Document, it should add "Hello" to Doc1 when clicked.

Hope this makes sense and apologies in advance if not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is not possible. In order to access and run code that's in a document, that document must be running in Word (open). VBA code can't run from a closed document.

Perhaps what you need is a dotm (template) that you load *as an add-in* - the code is loaded but the file is not opened in the usual sense of the term. Normal.dotm acts in this sense as an add-in, for example, but is also accessible to the user. Any other template loaded as an add-in is not accessible to the user the same way Normal.dotm is, but the code it contains is available in the same way.

The code in Doc1 can run code in an add-in, and the code in the add-in can work with any document currently open in the Word application.

Comment: Thank you Cindy. Without an add-in - can I open the secondary document, hide it except for its UserForm, and then get its UserForm to apply  to Master Document?

Comment: To add some context:

Comment: Currently I have 1000 documents and 20 UserForms.
Each document loads a single UserForm on opening. It also has 4-5 other UserForms accessible from the UserForm that's initially loaded.

Each document contains different combinations of the UserForms.

Right now, if a UserForm changes, we have to import it into all the Documents that are using it - after every change. This is really tedious.

My job is to explore how to improve the process so that a change to a single UserForm will reflect in all the documents using it (i.e. remove the manual importing process)